# Incremental count of duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following query displays duplicates in a table with the qty alias showing the total count, eg if there are five duplicates then all five will have the same qty = 5.

```
select s.*, t.* 
from [Migrate].[dbo].[Table1] s
join (
    select [date] as d1, [product] as h1, count(*) as qty
    from [Migrate].[dbo].[Table1]
    group by [date], [product]
    having count(*) > 1
) t on s.[date] = t.[d1] and s.[product] = t.[h1]
ORDER BY s.[product], s.[date], s.[id]
```

Is it possible to amend the `count(*) as qty` to show an incremental count so that five duplicates would display 1,2,3,4,5?

Comment: Please elaborate on how you identify a duplicate.

Comment: When `[date]` and `[product]` are both identical

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: @Teja - I would need at least columns [id] and [qty]. [id] is unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is `row_number()`.  How you use it is rather unclear, because you provide no guidance, such as sample data or desired results.  Hence this answer is rather general:

```
select s.*, t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by s.product order by s.date) as seqnum
from [Migrate].[dbo].[Table1] s join
     (select [date] as d1, [product] as h1, count(*) as qty
      from [Migrate].[dbo].[Table1]
      group by [date], [product]
      having count(*) > 1
     ) t
     on s.[date] = t.[d1] and s.[product] = t.[h1]
order by s.[product], s.[date], s.[id];
```

The  speculation is that the duplicates are by product.  This enumerates them by date.  Some combination of the `partition by` and `group by` is almost certainly what you need.